How to profile CPU cache miss/hit for Java apps?
I want to figure out the performance difference between two Java applications.
Both are tree-searching algorithms, but the faster one requires more pointer dereferences with less footprint (by static analysis).
I guess, the better performance derives from the better locality - higher CPU cache hit rate.
To verify my conjecture I tried to profile CPU cache performance with Intel VTune, however I found it is unsupported in the latest Intel VTune Profiler v2024.3.0:

Memory Access analysis is not supported inside a virtual machine since uncore events cannot be collected. For full functionality, consider using a bare-metal environment.

So, my question is: how can I profile the CPU cache performance for a Java app?
Or, is it silly to care about such low-level metrics for Java?
Really appreciate any suggestion or advice.

I don't think the issue is Java.  In this context "virtual machine" means a computer running under a hypervisor; e.g. in a cloud computing environment.  Bare metal environment refers to a setup where you are not using a hypervisor; e.g. a stand-alone PC or a classic server.

@StephenC thanks but I do run all apps in local host without virtualization, so I supposed it means jvm…

Well ... if we go by this page (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/vtune-profiler/user-guide/2023-0/java-code-analysis.html) VTune can be used to profile Java.  Maybe you should contact the vendor?

@StephenC Thank you! Your suggestion solved the problem. The environment supplied by the vendor is the key to the question (I was not granted as admin).

Maybe you can use async-profiler to capture cache-misses perf event: asprof -e cache-misses -d 10 jps . Or even the perf command itself
